# artifact.require() statement in inheritance?

Tags: migration, blockchain, solidity, truffle

Hi guys my question i very simple.
I have this contract:

**B.sol**

```
...
contract A {
    ...
}
contract B is A {
    ...
}
```

When i migrate to blockchain my B.sol i need to deploy every single contracts inside?
Choose one of the answers and explain why please.

1. ```
   var B = artifacts.require("B");

   module.exports = function(deployer) {
       deployer.deploy(B);
   };
   ```
2. ```
   var A= artifacts.require("A");
   var B= artifacts.require("B");

   module.exports = function(deployer) {
       deployer.deploy(A);
       deployer.deploy(B);
   };
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer you're looking for is most likely #1. When contracts inherit from other contracts, only a single contract is created during deployment. Conceptually, it's the same as other object-oriented languages. From the [Solidity docs](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/contracts.html#inheritance):

> When a contract inherits from multiple contracts, only a single
>   contract is created on the blockchain, and the code from all the base
>   contracts is copied into the created contract.

Technically, you can have a child contract that references a deployed parent contract (see below). But, I can't think of a situation where this would be a good design.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

contract A {
  uint256 public balance;

  function() public payable {
    balance = msg.value;
  }
}

contract B is A {
  uint256 i;
  A a;

  function B(address _a) public {
    a = A(_a);
  }

  function receiveForParent() public payable {
    a.transfer(msg.value);
  }

  function getParentBalance() public constant returns (uint256) {
    return a.balance();
  }
}
```

Here, you can deploy A then pass that address in when deploying B. In this case, calling `B.balance()` or using the fallback function is valid since you're inheriting the logic. However, `B.balance() != A.balance()`. (Note that `B.getParentBalance() == A.balance()`).